# ¿Cómo puedo añadir un slider como este a mi sitio web?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, slider

Quiero añadir un slider lo más parecido a este a mi sitio web. La cosa es que se mueva a esa velocidad y que se detenga cuando pases el cursor sobre el. La parte de que las imágenes estén linkeadas sí la sé hacer. No estoy muy familiarizado con js.

Si me pueden mencionar alguno, les agradezco de antemano.

http://rglaboratorios.com/sitio/

Comment: La pregunta es muy global y debería ser más clara. Intenta un código y posteriormente se te ayudará. Existen muchos tipos de sliders con Javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día.

Es muy fácil, el js que usan es este:
 https://amazingslider.com/es/

En la misma pagina viene la documentación, espero te sea útil. Si requieres mas ayuda me dices, para echarlo a andar en tu web.

https://amazingslider.com/es/como-insertar-un-slider-de-jquery-en-una-pagina-web/